# How to determine if doctrine query cache working in symfony applcation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Doctrine recommends to have query cache turned on on production environment, so in my `prod/doctrine.yaml` I have it turned on:

```yaml
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: false
        metadata_cache_driver:
            type: pool
            pool: doctrine.system_cache_pool
        query_cache_driver:
            type: pool
            pool: doctrine.system_cache_pool

framework:
    cache:
        pools:
            doctrine.system_cache_pool:
                adapter: cache.system
```

and my `cache.system` set up in `cacge.yaml` like this :

```yaml
framework:
    cache:
        system: cache.adapter.filesystem
```

also of course I added `./bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-query -e prod` to my deployment process. But I did not notice any speed improvements.

For now my `cache.system` adapter using filesystem. And I measure `var/cache/prod` size after running same endpoints with and without query cache turned on, and looks like cache size are the same, also it looks like structure of the cache the same.. I can see it's generating doctrine proxies and `default_metadata.php` file but I do not see any cache entries related to query cache.

Is there a way to determine that doctrine query cache working or not?